# accessing id from one class to another class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i want to access an id from class main to class fahim2_pop. want to access to word from textinput(in main class) to the popup widget which will appear when someone press the search button. when someone search "hello" and press search button the the popup widget will appear and in that popup widget the text of the label will be "hello" same as from the textinput. but the label and the id remains in different class. how to do it?

python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import *

class fahim2_pop(Popup):
    pass
class main(BoxLayout):  
    def word(self):
        pop=fahim2_pop()
        pop.open()

class CallApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return main()

CallApp().run()
```

kv code

```
Builder.load_string('''

<main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        TextInput:
            id:word
        Button:
            text:"search"
            on_press:root.word()

<fahim2_pop>:
    id:pop
    title:"result"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:app.root.ids.word.text 

''')
```

Comment: There are several ways to access an `id` from another class, but precisely how that would be done depends on how your app is structured (code you have not shared). That is why we ask that you post a [mcve].

Comment: I've added my full code. now please give a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `main` is the root of your app, you can access the `TextInput` from anywhere in your app using `App.get_running_app().root.ids.word`. So, you can get this in your `Popup` by using it in your `kv` as:

```
<fahim2_pop>:
    id:pop
    title:"result"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:app.root.ids.word.text
```

And you `fahim2_pop` can be simply:

```
class fahim2_pop(Popup):
    pass
```

Comment: what if main is not the root of my app? you said since main is the root it is text: app.root.ids.word.text.   but what if main is not the root? then it should be what?

Comment: There is no one answer to that question. It all depends on how your app is structured. You could save references to class instances, pass them among methods, or use instance references combined with the `ids` dictionary, or even use global variables.